# Azure Runbook can't modify Azure AD application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-runbook

I'm trying to execute this in an Azure Automation runbook

```
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $ApplicationId
$appRole = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AppRole
$appRole.AllowedMemberTypes = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$appRole.AllowedMemberTypes.Add("User");
$appRole.DisplayName = $TenantName + " Users"
$appRole.Id = New-Guid
$appRole.IsEnabled = $true
$appRole.Description = "Users of the tenant"
$appRole.Value = $TenantName

$app.AppRoles.Add($appRole)

Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $ApplicationId -AppRoles $app.AppRoles
```

Reading the application works fine, when I print the app variable I can see it's the correct application. Executing the script from my own machine also gives no errors. Yet executing it via the runbook gives me:

```
Set-AzureADApplication : Error occurred while executing SetApplication 
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

By now I have given the automation application registration in Azure AD all rights of the Active Directory API. I have also clicked "Grant Permissions". I know it's the correct app registration because the script also invites an external user, when I gave the correct rights on the "Graph Api" that started to work.

[image: configuration]

Comment: After your comment on my other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651889/how-to-add-app-roles-under-manifest-in-azure-active-directory-using-powershell-s/51663318#comment93354949_51663318 I tried out a runbook myself. Please see answer for details. I hope it solves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried out your exact script in a run book and to make it work, I had to add code to "Login as the service principal" just before your PowerShell script. You can see more details here:
[Using Azure Run As Account in Azure Automation](https://gotoguy.blog/2018/07/11/using-the-azure-run-as-account-in-azure-automation-to-connect-to-azure-ad-with-a-service-principal/)

On the permissions front, I only gave 1 application permission (i.e. "Read and write all applications") and then clicked "Grant Permissions" as it did need Admin consent. Steps were done by a user with "Global administrator" directory role in my Azure AD.

Here is my final working PowerShell script (copied from edit runbook):

```
# Get Azure Run As Connection Name
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
# Get the Service Principal connection details for the Connection name
$servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

# Logging in to Azure AD with Service Principal
"Logging in to Azure AD..."
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
    -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

$ApplicationId = "redacted-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxe3"
$TenantName = "RohitTenant"
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $ApplicationId
$appRole = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AppRole
$appRole.AllowedMemberTypes = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$appRole.AllowedMemberTypes.Add("User");
$appRole.DisplayName = $TenantName + " Users"
$appRole.Id = New-Guid
$appRole.IsEnabled = $true
$appRole.Description = "Users of the tenant"
$appRole.Value = $TenantName
$app.AppRoles.Add($appRole)

Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $ApplicationId -AppRoles $app.AppRoles
```

---

Here are screenshots from some other important steps that I followed, which you may or may not have done already.

1. Create Azure Run As account while creating automation account

   [image]
2. Make sure account settings for your automation account has the run as accounts now.

   [image]
3. Find the App Registration created for Run as Account and give it permission to read and write all Azure AD applications.

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: I swear I did all this yesterday. Today I revoked all permissions and added only the one you specfied. It started to work.