# When I'm trying to create app role with multiple allowedMemberTypes it throws error

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create an app role where I will have two allowedMemberTypes: **Application** and **Users**. But it throws errors: **Invalid value specified for property 'allowedMemberTypes' of resource 'AppRole'.**

Here are the cmdlets:

```
  $contributorRole = new-object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AppRole -Property @{
    IsEnabled = $true;
    Description = "Read/write access";
    DisplayName = "Contributor";
    AllowedMemberTypes = @("User", "Application");
    Id = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString();
    Value = "bcc.contributor";
  };

$myApp = New-AzureADApplication -Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow $true -Oauth2RequirePostResponse $true -DisplayName $displayName -AppRoles $contributorRole
```

Here is the result of the cmdlets

[image: Result]

If you remove the Application from the **$contributorRole** it will work.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54317429/9898643)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried testing couple of scenarios with your code and I was able to perform the operation you are trying to do .

Scenario 1: Create a new Azure AD application with App role

```
Connect-AzureAD 
$displayname = "Test1" 
$contributorRole = new-object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AppRole -Property @{ 
    IsEnabled = $true; 
    Description = "Read/write access"; 
    DisplayName = "Contributor"; 
    AllowedMemberTypes = @("User", "Application"); 
    Id = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); 
    Value = "bcc.contributor"; 
  }; 
$myApp = New-AzureADApplication -Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow $true -Oauth2RequirePostResponse $true -DisplayName $displayName -AppRoles
```

[image]

Scenario 2 : Create a app role on existing Azure AD application(AD application created via Portal)

```
Connect-AzureAD
$contributorRole = new-object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AppRole -Property @{
    IsEnabled = $true;
    Description = "Read/write access";
    DisplayName = "Contributor";
    AllowedMemberTypes = @("User", "Application");
    Id = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString();
    Value = "bcc.contributor";
  };

$myApp = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Test2'"
$change = Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectID $myApp.ObjectId -AppRoles $contributorRole
```

[image]

**Note: Using subscription  level account it has failed  would suggest you  login with  admin account of the azure AD i.e. admin@domainname.onmicrosoft.com**